# How to calculate the exact range of the analytic interval x of the piecewise function?

Tags: functions

Use:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{3^(x - 1), x <= 1}, {(2 - x)/(x - 1), x > 1}}]
f[f[x]] + 1/3 f[x] - 2 // PiecewiseExpand
```

Get the result:

[image]

The range of x in the red circle in the picture is not found. How can we find the range of x?

And for example:

`3^x > 3 && x <= 1`

There is no solution to this system of equations, and the corresponding analytic formula does not exist. And how to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = Piecewise[{{3^(x - 1), x <= 1}, {(2 - x)/(x - 1), x > 1}}];

expr = f[f[x]] + 1/3  f[x] - 2 // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify
```

[image]

[`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) the conditions

```
expr = expr /. {ex_, cond_} :> {ex, Reduce[cond, x]}
```

[image]

However, since the first condition will handle all `x <= 1`, the second condition can be simplified

```
expr = ReplacePart[
  expr, {1, 2, -1} -> Reduce[Simplify[expr[[1, 2, -1]], x > 1]]]
```

[image]